# Is it possible to use RRAS to create a tunnel over same subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, rras, tunneling

I would like to setup some form of secure tunnel between servers on the same lan.  We are currently using rackspace for cloud hosting, and would like to secure all communications over the 'private' lan interface via tunnels.

I can find numerous examples using openvpn such as (http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/CentOS_-_VPN_tunneling_with_OpenVPN) and (http://code.mixpanel.com/2010/09/08/openvpn-in-the-rackspace-cloud/) however I would prefer to use the built in features of windows to achieve the same thing if possible.

Does any one know of any good tutorials?

Thanks

Comment: can you not just enable IPSEC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no secret to configuring and connecting to a VPN between 2 hosts on the same LAN. The issue you're going to have is how to create VPN connections between all of the hosts on the LAN, which may not be possible. even if it is possible it's going to be fairly cumbersome and will probably prove to be pretty tricky to manage, not to mention getting all of the traffic to traverse the VPN connections.

That being said, what you're trying to accomplish isn't really suited to a VPN, it's better suited to IPSec. My suggestion would be to implement IPSec between the LAN hosts. Here's something to get you started:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deploy-ipsec-firewall-policies-step-by-step(WS.10).aspx